# Replace values of datatable1 against another datatable2 in r

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to use library(data.table) in r to efficiently replace values of datatable1 against another datatable2. Both datatables have 2mil+ records.

For example (simplified form):
datatable 1 looks like-

```
Source  Target  Col1    Col2
277 266 a   b
260 277 b   s
276 277 d   c
265 258 a   v
259 258 d   s
262 262 d   x
270 274 e   q
273 277 f   w
```

datatable 2:

```
ToBeMapStr  LookUpValue
256 1
257 2
258 3
259 4
260 5
261 6
262 7
263 8
264 9
265 10
266 11
267 12
268 13
269 14
270 15
271 16
272 17
273 18
274 19
275 20
276 21
277 22
```

The desired output in data.table1 should be:

```
Source  Target  Col1    Col2
22  11  a   b
5   22  b   s
21  22  d   c
10  3   a   v
4   3   d   s
7   7   d   x
15  19  e   q
18  22  f   w
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Did you try anything and have problems?

Comment: What you would need to do is an inner join on source and then an inner join on the target.https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/52230_5ae0d25125b544caab32f75f0360e775.html

Comment: Another option is to convert to long format, replace the values in a join, then (optionally) reshape back to wide format

Answer (score 0):

You can just use R Base for this using the function `match`.

generate example data

```
str1 <- 'Source  Target  Col1    Col2
277 266 a   b
260 277 b   s
276 277 d   c
265 258 a   v
259 258 d   s
262 262 d   x
270 274 e   q
273 277 f   w'

str2 <- 'ToBeMapStr  LookUpValue
256 1
257 2
258 3
259 4
260 5
261 6
262 7
263 8
264 9
265 10
266 11
267 12
268 13
269 14
270 15
271 16
272 17
273 18
274 19
275 20
276 21
277 22
'

file1 <- textConnection(str1)
file2 <- textConnection(str2)
dt1 <- read.table(file1, header = T)
dt2 <- read.table(file2, header = T)
```

replace values

```
dt1$Source <- dt2[match(dt1$Source,dt2$ToBeMapStr),'LookUpValue']
dt1$Target <- dt2[match(dt1$Target,dt2$ToBeMapStr),'LookUpValue']

dt1
```

result

```
  Source Target Col1 Col2
1     22     11    a    b
2      5     22    b    s
3     21     22    d    c
4     10      3    a    v
5      4      3    d    s
6      7      7    d    x
7     15     19    e    q
8     18     22    f    w
```